# Event of reaching the edge of window in correct way (onscroll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onscroll

Just in case, its my 1th question.

I have:
nav menu with transparent background and trying to change backrgound when  reached top edge of window.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", navSticky);
function navSticky(){
  let nav = document.getElementById('navbar');
  let bounding = nav.getBoundingClientRect();

  if(bounding.top <= 0 ){
      nav.classList.add("sticky");
  }else{
      nav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body{
  background: lightgrey;
}

header h1{
  padding: 40px;
}

nav{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
  rgba(0,0,0,0),
  rgba(0,255,0, 0.5), 
  rgba(255,0,0, 0.5),
  rgba(0,0,0,0));
  color: black;
}

nav:before{
  content: "now bg transparent";
}

.container{
  min-height: 1000px;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav.sticky{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
  rgb(0,255,0), 
  rgb(255,0,0));
  color: white;
}

nav.sticky:before{
  content: "now bg isn't transparent";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Header, that ask u to scroll page</h1> 
  </header>
  <nav id="navbar">
  </nav>
  <div class ="container">
      When we scroll page, and nav reached top of screen, .sticky add to classList<br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Its work, but I have several questions:

1. is it possible to do same without js?
2. is it possible to optimise this script cuz scroll event calling so often..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unfortunately no.
2. Yes, the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is a very good and performant solution for this specific issue.

The API allows you to *observe* elements when they enter or leave the viewport. It does this away from the main thread, so you won't get any render blocking code.

In your specific case, observe the `<header>` element. Whenever the element leaves the view is the same point when the `navbar` becomes sticky. In the callback check if the `isIntersecting` property is `true` or `false`. This property indicates if the observed element is (partially) in view or not.

```js
const header = document.querySelector('#header');
const nav = document.querySelector('#navbar');

const callback = ([entry]) => {
  const { isIntersecting } = entry;
  nav.classList.toggle('sticky', !isIntersecting);
};

const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(header);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background: lightgrey;
}

header h1 {
  padding: 40px;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  color: black;
}

nav:before {
  content: "now bg transparent";
}

.container {
  min-height: 1000px;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav.sticky {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0));
  color: white;
}

nav.sticky:before {
  content: "now bg isn't transparent";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header">
    <h1>Header, that ask u to scroll page</h1>
  </header>
  
  <nav id="navbar"></nav>
  
  <div class="container">
    When we scroll page, and nav reached top of screen, .sticky add to classList<br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it! Sorry, but i'm not allowed to +1 u yet.

Comment: Though you are allowed to accept answers ;)

Comment: ok, i did it! )

Comment: One moment:
when toggle switch off .sticky class, i get next:
<nav id="navbar" class>

is it a problem?

Comment: No, an empty `class` attribute is totally fine. `toggleClass` doesn't remove the attribute by itself as that is not its job.